# How to get all elements from an atomFamily in recoil?

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

Im playing around with recoil for the first time and cant figure out how I can read all elements from an atomFamily. Let's say I have an app where a user can add meals:

```
export const meals = atomFamily({
  key: "meals",
  default: {}
});
```

And I can initialize a meal as follows:

```
const [meal, setMeal] = useRecoilState(meals("bananas"));
const bananas = setMeal({name: "bananas", price: 5});
```

How can I read all items which have been added to this atomFamily?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to track all ids of the `atomFamily` to get all members of the family.
Keep in mind that this is not really a list, more like a map.

Something like this should get you going.

```js
// atomFamily
const meals = atomFamily({
  key: "meals",
  default: {}
});

const mealIds = atom({
  key: "mealsIds",
  default: []
});
```

When creating a new objects inside the family you also have to update the `mealIds` atom.

I usually use a `useRecoilCallback` hook to sync this together

```js
  const createMeal = useRecoilCallback(({ set }) => (mealId, price) => {
    set(mealIds, currVal => [...currVal, mealId]);
    set(meals(mealId), {name: mealId, price});
  }, []);
```

This way you can create a meal by calling:

```js
createMeal("bananas", 5);
```

And get all ids via:

```js
const ids = useRecoilValue(mealIds);
```

Comment: I see, so you need a separate atom to keep track of ids. Do you need snapshot here? Why should this be async? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah no need for async or snapshot. Updated answer.

Comment: In your example, how do you get all meals instead of all ids?

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian unless I'm mistaken, I believe that the solution is to take the value of the `mealIds` atom, an array, and then loop through it getting the value of each atom in the atom family with an id that corresponds to a value in from the array.

Comment: @flyingace That's an expensive operation no?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell To my mind it's not only expensive, it's also overly complicated. My team switched from trying out Recoil to using Redux Tool Kit. Using `createEntityAdapter` in RTK gives you both the separate table of ids and all of the elements those ids reference in a format that is much easier to manage. It may be that there is a simpler path to get this information in Recoil, but I was unable to find it as of v6.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, it tends to become quite complicated when it feels like it shouldn't.

Answer (score 20):

Instead of using `useRecoilCallback` you can abstract it with `selectorFamily`.

```js
// atomFamily
const mealsAtom = atomFamily({
  key: "meals",
  default: {}
});

const mealIds = atom({
  key: "mealsIds",
  default: []
});

// abstraction
const meals = selectorFamily({
  key: "meals-access",
  get:  (id) => ({ get }) => {
      const atom = get(mealsAtom(id));
      return atom;
  },
  set: (id) => ({set}, meal) => {
      set(mealsAtom(id), meal);
      set(mealIds (id), prev => [...prev, meal.id)]);
  }
});
```

Further more, in case you would like to support reset you can use the following code:

```js
// atomFamily
const mealsAtom = atomFamily({
  key: "meals",
  default: {}
});

const mealIds = atom({
  key: "mealsIds",
  default: []
});

// abstraction
const meals = selectorFamily({
  key: "meals-access",
  get:  (id) => ({ get }) => {
      const atom = get(mealsAtom(id));
      return atom;
  },
  set: (id) => ({set, reset}, meal) => {
      if(meal instanceof DefaultValue) {
        // DefaultValue means reset context
        reset(mealsAtom(id));
        reset(mealIds (id));
        return;
      }
      set(mealsAtom(id), meal);
      set(mealIds (id), prev => [...prev, meal.id)]);
  }
});
```

If you're using Typescript you can make it more elegant by using the following [guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

```js
import { DefaultValue } from 'recoil';

export const guardRecoilDefaultValue = (
  candidate: unknown
): candidate is DefaultValue => {
  if (candidate instanceof DefaultValue) return true;
  return false;
};
```

Using this guard with Typescript will look something like:

```js
// atomFamily
const mealsAtom = atomFamily<IMeal, number>({
  key: "meals",
  default: {}
});

const mealIds = atom<number[]>({
  key: "mealsIds",
  default: []
});

// abstraction
const meals = selectorFamily<IMeal, number>({
  key: "meals-access",
  get:  (id) => ({ get }) => {
      const atom = get(mealsAtom(id));
      return atom;
  },
  set: (id) => ({set, reset}, meal) => {
      if (guardRecoilDefaultValue(meal)) {
        // DefaultValue means reset context
        reset(mealsAtom(id));
        reset(mealIds (id));
        return;
      }
      // from this line you got IMeal (not IMeal | DefaultValue)
      set(mealsAtom(id), meal);
      set(mealIds (id), prev => [...prev, meal.id)]);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is this syntax `reset(mealIds (id));`? why is there a space b/w `mealIds` and `(id)`? @Bnaya

Comment: @Venugopal good point. I think OP accidentally used a list atom as it was an atomFamily. IMO This approach is fine as long as you manually pop the id from `mealIds` when  given an instance of `DefaultValue` i.e. `set(mealIds, (oldIds) => oldIds.filter((idList) => idList !== id));`

Comment: How does usage for reset (delete) look like?

Comment: How do you go about populating this?

Say you have an array of 5k meals from an API, do you have to just run through a loop and set every single `mealsAtom` and `mealIds`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `atom` to track the ids of each atom in the `atomFamily`. Then use a `selectorFamily` or a custom function to update the atom with the list of ids when a new atom is added or deleted from the `atomFamily`. Then, the atom with the list of ids can be used to extract each of the atoms by their id from the `selectorFamily`.

```
// File for managing state


//Atom Family
export const mealsAtom = atomFamily({
  key: "meals",
  default: {},
});
//Atom ids list
export const mealsIds = atom({
  key: "mealsIds",
  default: [],
});
```

This is how the `selectorFamily` looks like:

```
// File for managing state

export const mealsSelector = selectorFamily({
  key: "mealsSelector",
  get: (mealId) => ({get}) => {
    return get(meals(mealId));
  },
  set: (mealId) => ({set, reset}, newMeal) => {
    // if 'newMeal' is an instance of Default value, 
    // the 'set' method will delete the atom from the atomFamily.
    if (newMeal instanceof DefaultValue) {
      // reset method deletes the atom from atomFamily. Then update ids list.
      reset(mealsAtom(mealId));
      set(mealsIds, (prevValue) => prevValue.filter((id) => id !== mealId));
    } else {
      // creates the atom and update the ids list
      set(mealsAtom(mealId), newMeal);
      set(mealsIds, (prev) => [...prev, mealId]);
    }
  },
});
```

**Now, how do you use all this?**

- Create a meal:

In this case i'm using current timestamp as the atom id with `Math.random()`

```
// Component to consume state

import {mealsSelector} from "your/path";
import {useSetRecoilState} from "recoil";
const setMeal = useSetRecoilState(mealsSelector(Math.random()));

setMeal({
    name: "banana",
    price: 5,
});
```

- Delete a meal:

```
// Component to consume state

import {mealsSelector} from "your/path";
import {DefaultValue, useSetRecoilState} from "recoil";

const setMeal = useSetRecoilState(mealsSelector(mealId));
setMeal(new DefaultValue());
```

- Get all atoms from atomFamily:

Loop the list of ids and render Meals components that receive the id as props and use it to get the state for each atom.

```
// Component to consume state, parent of Meals component

import {mealsIds} from "your/path";
import {useRecoilValue} from "recoil";

const mealIdsList = useRecoilValue(mealsIds);

    //Inside the return function:
    return(
      {mealIdsList.slice()
          .map((mealId) => (
            <MealComponent
              key={mealId}
              id={mealId}
            />
          ))}
    );
```

```
// Meal component to consume state

import {mealsSelector} from "your/path";
import {useRecoilValue} from "recoil";

const meal = useRecoilValue(mealsSelector(props.id));
```

Then, you have a list of components for Meals, each with their own state from the `atomFamily`.

Comment: How would you batch add a list of meals? Say if you were to make a call to an API that returns an array of meals. Would you loop through that data and add the videos one by one?

Comment: @PGT Yes, atoms store individual items (e.g. a meal, a video) and not lists in this approach (e.g. meals, videos), so each one needs to be processed individually through a loop or map. The benefit of this granular approach comes when modifying just one item or just some of them by preventing re-rendering of the whole collection by modifying an entire list state

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I have it working on my current project:

(For context this is a dynamic form created from an array of field option objects. The form values are submitted via a graphql mutation so we only want the minimal set of changes made. The form is therefore built up as the user edits fields)

```
import { atom, atomFamily, DefaultValue, selectorFamily } from 'recoil';

type PossibleFormValue = string | null | undefined;

export const fieldStateAtom = atomFamily<PossibleFormValue, string>({
  key: 'fieldState',
  default: undefined,
});

export const fieldIdsAtom = atom<string[]>({
  key: 'fieldIds',
  default: [],
});

export const fieldStateSelector = selectorFamily<PossibleFormValue, string>({
  key: 'fieldStateSelector',
  get: (fieldId) => ({ get }) => get(fieldStateAtom(fieldId)),
  set: (fieldId) => ({ set, get }, fieldValue) => {
    set(fieldStateAtom(fieldId), fieldValue);
    const fieldIds = get(fieldIdsAtom);
    if (!fieldIds.includes(fieldId)) {
      set(fieldIdsAtom, (prev) => [...prev, fieldId]);
    }
  },
});

export const formStateSelector = selectorFamily<
  Record<string, PossibleFormValue>,
  string[]
>({
  key: 'formStateSelector',
  get: (fieldIds) => ({ get }) => {
    return fieldIds.reduce<Record<string, PossibleFormValue>>(
      (result, fieldId) => {
        const fieldValue = get(fieldStateAtom(fieldId));
        return {
          ...result,
          [fieldId]: fieldValue,
        };
      },
      {},
    );
  },
  set: (fieldIds) => ({ get, set, reset }, newValue) => {
    if (newValue instanceof DefaultValue) {
      reset(fieldIdsAtom);
      const fieldIds = get(fieldIdsAtom);
      fieldIds.forEach((fieldId) => reset(fieldStateAtom(fieldId)));
    } else {
      set(fieldIdsAtom, Object.keys(newValue));
      fieldIds.forEach((fieldId) => {
        set(fieldStateAtom(fieldId), newValue[fieldId]);
      });
    }
  },
});
```

The atoms are selectors are used in 3 places in the app:

In the field component:

```
...
const localValue = useRecoilValue(fieldStateAtom(fieldId));
const setFieldValue = useSetRecoilState(fieldStateSelector(fieldId));
...
```

In the save-handling component (although this could be simpler in a form with an explicit submit button):

```
...
const fieldIds = useRecoilValue(fieldIdsAtom);
const formState = useRecoilValue(formStateSelector(fieldIds));
...
```

And in another component that handles form actions, including form reset:

```
...
const resetFormState = useResetRecoilState(formStateSelector([]));
...
const handleDiscard = React.useCallback(() => {
  ...
  resetFormState();
  ...
}, [..., resetFormState]);
```

Comment: Maybe slightly offtopic, but curious since this approach works pretty well I must say. How do you handle validation errors?