# Recoil: parent state does not update when atomFamily is set

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I have a React functional component subscribed to a Recoil atomFamily. The intent is that the atomFamily will update one item in the parent state, and then another component depending on the parent state will re-render via `useEffect`. However, this does not appear to be happening. Why could this be? From what it would look like (and my own experimentation) changing *part* of the parent state using a Recoil selector should automatically propagate back to the parent.

The selector state item looks like this:

```js
import { atomFamily, selectorFamily } from "recoil";
import { GroupInterface } from './../interfaces/GroupInterface';
import { GroupList } from './GroupList';

export const GroupSelector = atomFamily({
    key: "GroupSelector",
    default: selectorFamily({
        key: "GroupSelector/default",
        get: id => ({get}): GroupInterface => {
            const groupList = get(GroupList);

            return groupList.find((group) => group.id === id) as GroupInterface
        }
    })
})
```

The parent state item looks like this:

```js
import { atom } from 'recoil';
import { GroupInterface } from '../interfaces/GroupInterface';

export const GroupList = atom({
    key: "GroupList",
    default: [] as GroupInterface[]
})
```

The component that needs to be updated after the atomFamily is set is done as follows:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentActiveSwaps(getCurrentActiveSwaps(groupList));
    // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [groupList])
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you assigned an atomFamily to GroupSelector,

```
GroupSelector = atomFamily({
```

then its default value of that atom is set to a selectorFamily,

```
 default: selectorFamily({
```

Normally, you would have an array or object as the default value. Using a selectorFamily as default value is interesting, not sure where it will lead though.

Here is a good example,

[How to get all elements from an atomFamily in recoil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64433884/how-to-get-all-elements-from-an-atomfamily-in-recoil)