# How to get all ids from an atomFamily?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, recoiljs

I am currently using the Recoil library in my project and I am having some trouble with how to store the ids for an atomFamily. I have looked at [solutions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64433884/how-to-get-all-elements-from-an-atomfamily-in-recoil) and the common answer seems to be using an array, but I'm not happy with this solution because it's causing performance issues for me & I can't figure out how to incrementally load all the items onto a screen using this method.

Is there a better and more efficient way to store the ids for an atomFamily in Recoil? I would really appreciate if anyone could share any alternative methods they have tried. Thank you!

Example:

```
const meals = atomFamily({
  key: "meals",
  default: {}
});

const mealIds = atom({
  key: "mealsIds",
  default: []
});
```